# problem using tkinter treeview widget and page gui builder

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am new to python and trying to build a GUI app using PAGE GUI builder
I have a treeView widget on my page and here is my function in the support module:

```py
def initTree():
    for i in w.prefTreeviewScTrv.get_children():
        w.prefTreeviewScTrv.delete(i)
    w.prefTreeviewScTrv["columns"]=("one","two","three")
    w.prefTreeviewScTrv.column("#0", width=270, minwidth=270, stretch=tk.NO)
    w.prefTreeviewScTrv.column("one", width=150, minwidth=150, stretch=tk.NO)
    w.prefTreeviewScTrv.column("two", width=400, minwidth=200)
    w.prefTreeviewScTrv.column("three", width=80, minwidth=50, stretch=tk.NO)
    w.prefTreeviewScTrv.heading("#0",text="Name",anchor=tk.W)
    w.prefTreeviewScTrv.heading("one", text="Date modified",anchor=tk.W)
    w.prefTreeviewScTrv.heading("two", text="Type",anchor=tk.W)
    w.prefTreeviewScTrv.heading("three", text="Size",anchor=tk.W)
    # Level 1
    w.prefTreeviewScTrv.insert("", 1, "", text="first_file.txt", values=("22-Jun-16 11:25","first file","0.5 KB"))
    folder1=w.prefTreeviewScTrv.insert("", 2, "", text="Folder 1", values=("23-Jun-17 11:05","File folder",""))
    w.prefTreeviewScTrv.insert("", 3, "", text="text_file.txt", values=("23-Jun-17 11:25","TXT file","1 KB"))
    # Level 2
    w.prefTreeviewScTrv.insert(folder1, "end", "", text="photo1.png", values=("23-Jun-17 11:28","PNG file","2.6 KB"))
    w.prefTreeviewScTrv.insert(folder1, "end", "", text="photo2.png", values=("23-Jun-17 11:29","PNG file","3.2 KB"))
    w.prefTreeviewScTrv.insert(folder1, "end", "", text="photo3.png", values=("23-Jun-17 11:30","PNG file","3.1 KB"))
```

Whenever I run the program, it runs and create the tree columns and heading properly
but I get an exception when using the insert method no matter what index I give the item 0 or 1:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\page\tenders\notebook_support.py", line 127, in <module>
      notebook.vp_start_gui()
    File "C:\page\tenders\notebook.py", line 30, in vp_start_gui
      notebook_support.init(root, top)
    File "C:\page\tenders\notebook_support.py", line 115, in init
      initTree()
    File "C:\page\tenders\notebook_support.py", line 102, in initTree
      w.prefTreeviewScTrv.insert("", 1, "", text="first_file.txt", values=("22-Jun-16 11:25","first file","0.5 KB"))
    File "C:\Users\ori\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\ttk.py", line 1365, in insert
      res = self.tk.call(self._w, "insert", parent, index, _tkinter.TclError: Item  already exists
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the code you're issuing to insert an item?

Comment: You are defining: `w.prefTreeviewScTrv["columns"]=("one","two","three")`: but it seems that there are 4 columns. Have you forgotten the first column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that every time you insert an item, you set its ID to `""`. This is the ID of the root item. Because different items must have different IDs, this doesn't work. You need to remove the third argument in all calls to `insert()`:

```py
# Level 1
w.prefTreeviewScTrv.insert("", 1, text="first_file.txt", values=("22-Jun-16 11:25","first file","0.5 KB"))
folder1=w.prefTreeviewScTrv.insert("", 2, text="Folder 1", values=("23-Jun-17 11:05","File folder",""))
w.prefTreeviewScTrv.insert("", 3, text="text_file.txt", values=("23-Jun-17 11:25","TXT file","1 KB"))
# Level 2
w.prefTreeviewScTrv.insert(folder1, "end", text="photo1.png", values=("23-Jun-17 11:28","PNG file","2.6 KB"))
w.prefTreeviewScTrv.insert(folder1, "end", text="photo2.png", values=("23-Jun-17 11:29","PNG file","3.2 KB"))
w.prefTreeviewScTrv.insert(folder1, "end", text="photo3.png", values=("23-Jun-17 11:30","PNG file","3.1 KB"))
```

Comment: Or, the OP can generate valid IDs…